# Return a button object by its name in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I’m developing an application in C# which works with several forms  and I would like to implement a method to set the properties of these forms. For each one of these forms, two buttons named “okBtn” and “cancelBtn” were created through Designer. I would like to set the form AcceptButton property as “okBtn” and the form CancelButton property as ”cancelBtn”, but I don’t know how to return the buttons objects by their names. Follow a sample that what I’m trying to do:

```
static public void SetDialogAppearance(Form form)
{
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;            
    form.Icon = PresentationLayer.Properties.Resources.embraer;
    form.MinimizeBox = false;
    form.MaximizeBox = false;
    form.AcceptButton = form.Controls["okBtn"]; //this returns an error
    form.CancelButton = form.Controls["cancelBtn"]; //this returns an error
}
```

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms? WPF? UWP?

Comment: Can you add how you are creating the `okBtn` and `cancelBtn` buttons please?

Comment: Given `Form` class is used I guess it's WinForms. In that case, if the controls are public fields, you can access like you would do normally, `form.okBtn`, assuming you know the names at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue doing this:

- I created a class that inherit the Form class and with the buttons declared as public fields:

```
    public class OkCancelForm : Form
    {
        public IButtonControl AcceptBtn { get; set; }
        public IButtonControl CancelBtn { get; set; }
    }
```

- In the forms, this class is inherited and in the constructor the form buttons are assigned to the fields:

```
    public partial class MyForm : OkCancelForm
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AcceptBtn = this.okBtn;
            CancelBtn = this.cancelBtn;            
        }
```

- Finally, I used these fields in the SetDialogAppearance class:

```
    static public void SetDialogAppearance(OkCancelForm form)
        {
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;            
            form.Icon = PresentationLayer.Properties.Resources.embraer;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.AcceptButton = form.AcceptBtn;
            form.CancelButton = form.CancelBtn;
            form.KeyPreview = true;            
        }
```

I don’t know if it’s the best solution (neither the most elegant) but it does work. If someone has a better suggestion I’d really appreciate to know.